# How can I show a ManyToManyField value filtered on the basis of ForeignKey while editing an django model object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have four models in my models.py which are:

**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    elective_group = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Unit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Pattern(models.Model):
    pattern_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ExamSchedule(models.Model):
    exam_date = models.DateTimeField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    pattern = models.ForeignKey(Pattern)
    **units = models.ManyToManyField(Units)**
```

I have all these models register with admin site, so that I can use admin functionality for these models.

My problem is when a user creates or edits a `ExamSchedule` object, I want the units(field) multivalue widget should contains only those values that are associated with a course as every course can have multiple units. So if user creates an `Examschedule` object and after selecting a course from dropdown the unit widget should only contains those units that related to the course selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used this django plugin to do this exact thing in the admin sections. I believe it also works in the front end as well:

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: Its close to my solution but I don't think so that this plugin would help me as this is only for "foreignKey" chained selection,  in my case i want to filter the unit based on course and then give user a multiselect option for units nor single select option. Correct in if i am wrong....